# Flutter: How to make an accurate timer in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-timer

I know to make a timer in flutter but as other platforms for e.g. game engines and android studio there is always a delta value that is the difference between two frames and it ensures accuracy. In flutter I fund no way to access delta. There is a stopwatch class but does it contain delta and is it completely accurate.

Please help.